# Corresponding ldap query for "dsquery partition"

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

Is there a way I can find all partitions using a LDAP query? 
I have a parent domain and a number of child domains in my Active Directory. The global catalog is set on the child domain and I want to search all partitions on all parent as well as child domains in the Active directory from here.

Running "dsquery partition" on the child domain gives me the list but I am writing a Python program to get this. Currently I am using the following python-ldap method which gives me only the current child domain's partitions.

```
baseDNs = conn.search_s('', ldap.SCOPE_BASE,
                                '(objectClass=*)', ['namingContexts'])
```

What parameters should I pass to this method so that I can see all partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab all the crossRef objects `(objectClass=crossRef)` in the CN=Partitions container of the forest's configuration naming context and you'll have what you need.

Comment: Thanks but this is half helpful. For example, the following dsquery gives me correct DNs for the partitions but the corresponding search_s() method doesn't show this attribute.  The dsquery is **dsquery * "cn=partitions,cn=configuration,<forestrootDN>" -scope subtree -filter "(objectClass=crossRef)" -attr nCName**. The corresponding search_s() method I am using is **conn.search_s('cn=partitions,cn=configuration,<forestrootDN>', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=crossRef)", ['nCName'])** which gives me a blank output

Comment: I don't have any Python know-how to speak of. Is it possible to grab a network trace from the box where you're testing this and see what the actual LDAP request looks like? That would be my starting point.

Comment: I was connecting to the global catalog port which doesn't have this attribute. Connected to the LDAP port and it showed the the nCName attribute. Thanks for all the help.